# Passing an array to a function and using sizeof in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I'm an Arduino [padawan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/padawan#Noun) learner. I want to pass a byte array to a function and get the size of the array.

```
byte data[] = {
    B00000000,
    B00000001,
    B00000011,
    B00000111
};

Serial.println(sizeof(data)); // ----------------------> displays 4
```

When I pass it to a function `sizeof` returns 2. How can I get it to return 4 also in the function?

```
writeData(data);

void writeData(byte data[]) {
    Serial.println(sizeof(data)); // -------------------> displays 2
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When e.g. passing arrays as parameters, the compiler no longer has the size of the array. Instead the array gets passed as a pointer, and in `writeData` the `sizeof` operation gets the size of the pointer and not the array (or whatever) it points to.

Comment: Yes to the above.  Also, the canonical solution is to pass a pointer and a size.  void writeData(const byte* data, size_t size);

Comment: Ok thanks.  @JoshPetitt used solution and got it working now as intended.

Comment: I often get hung up on this issue.  Thanks for the clarification +1